# Search for a substring in cell and return value of matrix

Tags: string, excel, substring, excel-2010, vba

the following excel tables are given:

**Sheet01**
String: A 
Output: B

```
+---------------------+--------------+
|       String        |    Output    |
+---------------------+--------------+
| ABC Test01          | It is Test01 |
| DEF Test01          | It is Test01 |
| Test01 GHI          | It is Test01 |
| Hellow Test02 World | Wow Test02   |
| Test02 Sum Sing     | Wow Test02   |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

**Sheet02**

Search Criteria: A

 OutputThis: B

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| Search Criteria |  OutputThis  |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Test01          | It is Test01 |
| Test02          | Wow Test02   |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

So basically I want to find out if *Search Criteria* in Sheet02 can be found in *String* in Sheet01. 
 If so, display in *Output* (Sheet01) value of *OutputThis* (Sheet02).

Following works for exact match:

```
=INDEX(Sheet02!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet02!A:A,0))
```

Now I simply tried to put in the like operator which doesn't make any sense. Because excel can't now what part of String is to be found in Search Criteria.

What I'm looking for is something

```
=New_Function(SearchCriteriaMatrix, SearchCell, OutputMatrix)
```

**EDIT:**

I just used the following code and it somehow works:

`=INDEX(Sheet02!B:B,Match(A2,Sheet02!A:A,-1))`

The key is "-1". It changes the criteria from an exact match to a broad match. At least that's what I want it to do, but it doesn't workout well. Perhaps someone can use this and help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a single cell array formula:

1. In cell `Sheet01!B2` type:
    
   `=INDEX(Sheet02!B:B,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Sheet02!A:A,A2)),0,1),0))`

   Press ctrl+shift+enter to complete the formula as single cell array formula

   Copy this cell down to the remaining range `Sheet01!B3:B6`

Note: It gives the output for the first `Sheet02` Search Criteria that matches, and not the first one found in the string. So the string `Test02 and Test01` would output `It is Test01` because `Test01` is listed before `Test02` on `Sheet02`.

Comment: This is kind of brilliant! It does work, but seems to be inefficient cause it loads for up to a minute to when u work in the sheets.

Comment: Well yeah, because what you're asking for literally fits the definition of convoluted and will not scale well. The only faster way I know of to do what you're asking would be to write code that compiles Sheet02 into a [DFSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). Although if you wrote VBA to do the copy down part you could have it run blocks at a time and paste by values as you go, which may help a bit.

Comment: Also cutting down the cell references from the whole column to just the area you're interested in will help too. IE `Sheet02!$A$2:$A$3` and `Sheet02!$B$2:$B$3` instead of `Sheet02!A:A` and `Sheet02!B:B`

Comment: cutting down the references improved the performance absolutely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SEARCH` or `FIND` can find a substring within a string.  So something like:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(srchCritTbl[Search Criteria],A2),srchCritTbl[OutputThis])
```

will work.

I made your sheet2 table into a "real" table and I'm using structured references, but it'll work with discrete references also, but the references should encompass only the active part of the data table, and not the entire column.

Here is a screen shot showing the results:

[image]

If you were to use direct references to the table on Sheet02, it would look like:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(Sheet02!$A$2:$A$3,
Sheet01!$A2),Sheet02!$B$2:$B$3)
```

The way this works:

- `SEARCH` returns an array of either a number, or an error, depending on whether or not if finds the contents of table2 within the referenced cell in table 1.
- `1/Search(...` will then return either an error, or some number which has to be no greater than 1.
- Using `2` as the lookup criteria in `LOOKUP` guarantees that it will be greater than any value returned in the `lookup_vector`.
- If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value. **EDIT:** As pointed out by @Gregory, this applies if lookup_vector is sorted ascending.  When it is not, then the last entry that is less than or equal to lookup_value gets matched.
- since `result_vector` references the `OutputThis` column, the matching entry in that column would be returned.

One could also guarantee, in this situation, that `lookup_value` would be greater than any value in `lookup_vector` by using a very large number, and eliminating the `1/...` portion:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,SEARCH(srchCritTbl[Search Criteria],Sheet01!$A2),srchCritTbl[OutputThis])
```

I used the other form out of habit as it is more generally useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Could you also please explain the 2,1/... part? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something crucial.

Comment: +1, worked for me and avoided the array formula. Although I believe you may have misspoken when you said "the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value"; because the string "Test01 and Test02", gives me the result "Wow Test02" and 1/1 should be > 1/12, so I would expect "It is Test01" instead.

Comment: @Gregory good pickup.  The quote is copy/paste from MS Help for the function. However, that comment presumes `lookup_vector` is in an ascending sorted order.  It is really matching the last entry in `lookup_vector` that is <= `lookup_value`

Comment: Maybe a Note: it gives the output for the last `Sheet02` Search Criteria that matches, and not the first one found in the string. So by extension the string `Test01 and Test03 and Test02` would give `Test03`'s Output when defined on `Sheet02` in the order `Test01`, `Test02`, `Test03`.